# Django Template: How to display the value of Foreign Key in a values_list

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am passing the foreign key id in the values_list to the template and so my template can only show the id of the referenced object.  I would like to get the actual object though without explicitly passing the fields.

## models.py:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
''' This class will host RBC raw data. '''
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    transaction_date = models.DateField()
    cheque_number = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null = True, blank = True)
    description_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
    description_2 = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
    cad = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, blank = True, null = True)
    usd = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, blank = True, null = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank = True, null = True, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    category = models.ForeignKey('BudgetCategory', blank = True, null = True, on_delete = models.PROTECT) # same as above comment
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('BudgetSubCategory', blank = True, null = True, on_delete = models.PROTECT)  # Does not delete related sub-categories if a transaction is delted.
```

## views.py:

```
transaction_fields = ['account_type', 'account_number', 'transaction_date', 'description_1', 'description_2','cad', 'category', 'subcategory'] 
field_order_by = ['category', 'subcategory', 'description_1', 'transaction_date']

class AllRecordsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'transactions'

    fields = transaction_fields
    field_order_by = field_order_by
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

        transactions = Transaction.objects.all().values_list(*self.fields).order_by(*field_order_by)

        return transactions


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AllRecordsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        column_fields = fields_to_columns(self.fields)  # returns the name of columns in capitalized form and changing underscore to space
        context['fields'] = column_fields               # Adding a context variable called field which hosts the column names list
        return context
```

## Template:

```
{% for transaction in transactions %}
        <tr>
            {% for field in transaction %}
                <td>  {{ field }} </td>
        </tr>
```

In other words, I am trying to avoid passing all transaction objects and calling each field separately:

```
<tr>
{% for transaction in transactions %}
    <td> {{ transaction.account_type }} </td>
    ...
    <td>
         {{ transaction.category.name }}
   </td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Is there anyway that I can maintain code versatility and display the foreign key objects' attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access traverse relationships by using the double underscore notation similar to how you do in a filter call. Such as:

```
Class A:
    b = ForeignKey(B)

class B:
    description = CharField()

A.objects.all().values_list('b__description')
```

So for yours it seems like you'd change `transaction_fields` to include a `'related_obj__field_needed'` value in the list.